# Datastax Rack Issue

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

We are using Cassandra Enterprise Edition with Opscenter.
We have added node from Opscenter. **During adding we did not defined any RACK but still its showing RACK in Opscenter**.

Please help to get it solved.

[image]

```
[root@cassandra-2 ~]# nodetool status
Datacenter: singapore
=====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address          Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.145.23  1.07 GB    1            ?       hostid-1  rack1
UN  192.168.141.28  64.03 GB   1            ?       hostid-2  
UN  192.168.147.3   64.07 GB   1            ?       hostid-3
```

Comment: It would help if you can paste output of nodetool status or nodetool ring command if you are using single token nodes.

Comment: I updated in description.